# Random facebook profile id generator

Tags: xcode, facebook, uiimageview

Right I have a programme that displays a profile facebook profile picture when a button is touched accessed by using the graph api as shown. in the url:
http://graph.facebook.com/517418990/picture?type=large
The number can be changed to show a different profile picture (some numbers dont work but that is a different question. How in xcode can i firstly generate a random number (i assume it has to have some kind of structure not just a random 9 digit number) and secondly how can i load a new random number with each push of the button. E.g. push button = display profile of random number, push 2 = display profile of new random number etc etc. Some of the code below is not completely relevant because i also have an array with some images in it that to go through. Thanks in advance!

@interface FacebookPicturesViewController : UIViewController {

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
NSInteger imageCount;
NSArray *imageArray;
NSString *profileLink;
```

}
- (IBAction) nextImagePush;
@end

@implementation FacebookPicturesViewController

- (IBAction) nextImagePush {

  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://graph.facebook.com/517418990/picture?type=large"]]];
  [imageView setImage:img];

  if (imageCount >= [imageArray count]){
      imageCount = 0;
  }
  }
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1", @"image2", nil];
  imageCount = 0;
  }